# Matrices to model 3D object

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm toying around with an algorithm to determine placement of 3D objects into a larger 3D space. I immediately thought of using matrices.

It's been some years since my Linear Algebra courses. I was hoping someone could provide some references or even examples to help get me started.

Bonus points for:

- Collision detection
- Object rotation
- Alternatives to matrices

Answer (score 3):

The question is too broad to provide specific examples. If you want a reference, I highly recommend [Real-Time Rendering](http://amzn.com/1568814240). Chapters that would interest you:

- Chapter 4, Transforms: Covers matrix transformations and operations, including object rotation. It also covers [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) which are the usual alternatives to matrices. One of the advantages of quaternions is that they don't suffer from [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).
- Chapter 16, Intersection Test Methods: Covers numerous algorithms for detecting collisions between various shapes.
- Chapter 17, Collision Detection: Covers advanced collision detection algorithms like BSP trees.

The book provides a summary of the linear algebra needed in the appendix if you need a review. The other chapters contain a wealth of information on computer graphics. If you are into this field, you can't go wrong with this book.